# How to remove or trim special characters/prefixes from payload in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I need to trim/remove the special characters from a payload.
example- input-

```
�~�{
  "Employee": "Sara",
  "number": {
    "id": "d1q2",
    "designation": "CYUL"
      }
}
```

output-

```
{
  "Employee": "Sara",
  "number": {
    "id": "d1q2",
    "designation": "CYUL"
      }
}
```

I am trying to remove the before characters of "Employee" before curly braces in the beginning whatever is present should be removed and just a JSON structure should be present starting from curly braces and before whatever comes should be removed tried everything unable to do. Please help me in resolving my issue.

Comment: Hi! Are you reading that from a file directly? Looks like the UTF BOM mark. Maybe just setting the right encoding (UTF-8) on the `MIME Type` tab of the file read solves the problem.

Comment: It doesn't look to be a BOM mark but it is similar. Maybe it got corrupted when copying it here. It would be good to know the characters in hexadecimal to avoid confusions. In any case DataWeave doesn't support BOM marks.

Comment: Hi Jorge,
I tried addingthe Mime type but it is not working. characters are still present.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the payload as JSON because those characters are not valid in JSON and the DataWeave parser will throw an error. If you can read the payload as `text/plain` then you can use DataWeave to remove the 4 extra characters from the beginning and re read the remaining data as a JSON, and set the output to JSON too.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload[4 to -1], "application/json")
```

If you already read the payload you could try setting its MIME type before executing the DataWeave Transform: `<set-payload value="#[payload]" mimeTpy="text/plain"/>`.

Comment: Hi Aled,
Thank you for responding but it is not working. am trying to read from a websocket listener, whatever i get as a payload before that we have some special character prefixes which the above code is not removing and I also tried  setting the payload as text/plain even that is not working.

Comment: Hi @aled , I am working with websocket connectors. These connectors behave differently while receiving the payload. So, I made one more xml file and tried calling that service, it provides the Json payload with special chars but am removing them by reading it as Json payload read(payload, 'application/json) and it works then am doing some transformation.
Thank you for the response means a lot. :)